# How to clip a movie from specified start time in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to clip some movie from time A to time B using `ffmpeg`.

I can set how long the target video should be using the `-t` flag, but how should I tell it to start that time from time A?

In other words: I have a movie with the length of 10 minutes – I want to clip it to get only 5 minutes of it, starting from minute 2. How can I tell `ffmpeg` what I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You you tried the `-ss` option? From the [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html#SEC5) documentation:

> `-ss position'
>
> Seek to given time position in seconds. hh:mm:ss[.xxx] syntax is also supported.

Comment: I've tried that but the point was I had to put it before -i option i've always tried it after that.

Comment: appears that location of -ss makes a difference: http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Seeking%20with%20FFmpeg

Answer (score 0):

You could use dmMediaConverter with Split option, it will do it quickly without re-encoding. It is a ffmpeg GUI.
http://dmsimpleapps.blogspot.com/2014/04/dmmediaconverter.html
[image]